# How to connect to suite CRM REST API using Guzzle

Tags: rest, codeigniter-3, sugarcrm, guzzle, suitecrm

I'm trying to connect to suite CRM REST API using Guzzle

```
   $res = $client->request('GET','http://crm.demo.com/service/v4_1/rest.php/login', [   "auth" => [ 'myadmin', md5('mypswd') ]]);

    print_r($res);
```

The result I'm getting is this

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
(
[reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => OK
[statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 200
[headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
    (
        [Date] => Array
            (
                [0] => Mon, 03 Apr 2017 06:26:17 GMT
            )

        [Content-Type] => Array
            (
                [0] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            )

        [Transfer-Encoding] => Array
            (
                [0] => chunked
            )

        [Connection] => Array
            (
                [0] => keep-alive
            )

        [Set-Cookie] => Array
            (
                [0] => __cfduid=daace974785b1e202e7535232346958d111491200776; expires=Tue, 03-Apr-18 06:26:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.demo.com; HttpOnly
            )

        [X-Powered-By] => Array
            (
                [0] => PHP/5.4.16
            )

        [X-Varnish] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2592144
            )

        [Age] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [Via] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1.1 varnish-v4
            )

        [Server] => Array
            (
                [0] => cloudflare-nginx
            )

        [CF-RAY] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3499f497d6bd17a4-SIN
            )

    )

[headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
    (
        [date] => Date
        [content-type] => Content-Type
        [transfer-encoding] => Transfer-Encoding
        [connection] => Connection
        [set-cookie] => Set-Cookie
        [x-powered-by] => X-Powered-By
        [x-varnish] => X-Varnish
        [age] => Age
        [via] => Via
        [server] => Server
        [cf-ray] => CF-RAY
    )

[protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
[stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
    (
        [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #73
        [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
        [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
        [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
        [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

 )
```

Its showing the request was successful but I'm not getting the result. Is it really possible to connect it using Guzzle? Is there any other method to pass the login parameters?

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 and Guzzle to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what's the issue? You code is correct, you get the response.

If you want to explore the response body, just do `(string) $res->getBody()` or `$res->getBody()->getContents()` (the body is a stream, as you can in your dump, so to get it as a string you have to do additional actions).

BTW, you are trying to access a site under CloudFlare, and usually it's not possible, because CloudFlare rejects robots. Try to get a different entry point (that is not under CloudFlare protection).

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Shockov for pointing out that cloudflare issue.I was little confused about the response.Now i got it working